# MongoDB Atlas secondary shards remain idle

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, sharding, mongodb-atlas

I was doing some load tests on our servers connected to mongodb atlas. While looking at the atlas metrics, it seemed to me that the secondary(replicas) remain idle.

In the screenshots below, the right most graph is the primary node:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the only graph showing data is the primary node. Is this expected behavior or am I missing something from my config?

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior if you were doing primary reads.